# Blacklist Powershell packages

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, packages, blacklist

Hello everyone since there is no discussion about blacklisting PowerShell packages (at least I think that there is none), I am asking you here. I asked same question on Stackoverflow but it was off topic there, so I hope that it won´t be here.

We are currently working with Docker on 3 different servers and use the BcContainerHelper package to create Containers with Business Central running on them. But once so often a colleague installs an outdated package that can cause problems.

So now to my question: Is there any way to prevent the installation of certain packages via Powershell? I thought of some sort of blacklist with all the packages that are prohibited from being installed. Is that possible, I have not yet found anything about blacklisting or blocking the installation of packages?

I hope there is a fairly easy solution to that, and even if it is a bit more complex, I would be really greatful for any suggestions.

Happy creating and greetings Silent3rror

Comment: I don't think there is. But installing modules require you to run PowerShell as admin, and most queries don't need powershell to be run as admin. So if you can ensure those people are not administrators, you should be fine already.

Comment: Ok, but isn´t there any other workaround than admin? Because in our small comp nearly everyone is able to run the shell as admin. But thx for the answer.

Comment: You are asking for a technical constraint for a human control problem. So, this is a very opinioned (or looking for software or environment-specific) kind of thing, for the most part. Hence the reason you were told it was off-topic because it's not a PowerShell coding issue/problem or control. `Rule #1: Admin, means admin. God on the box. If you don't trust them, then they should not be admins.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any built-in way to deny PS packages; but there are paid tools that allow you to  manage PS modules, e.g. [PowerShell ModuleManager](https://www.sapien.com/store/software/powershell-modulemanager)

It comes with a feature that allows you disabling modules
See; https://info.sapien.com/index.php/how-to/powershell-module-manager-how-to/disabling-modules-with-powershell-modulemanager

This is probably not exactly what you had in mind but there is not much else it looks like.

Comment: That would be, I guess, the easiest way but my comp. won´t pay $60 for a program that we only use for one package. Good solution to the "problem" but won´t pay off at the end.

Comment: I am also not a big fan of proprietary software and I am not trying to sell something (in fact I just googled it) but when the tool saves your company just one hour per year it could already pay off.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I didn´t want it to sound like you want to sell me that piece of software. That is absolutely not how I meant it! Further, you are right it pays off easily and can be used for future project (getting them ready faster). But unfortunatly I am not the one in charge so I guess I just have to take it as it is ;).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot block specific packages.

1. You can set repos as trusted or untrusted.
2. You can build your own internal repo, and place modules there for
   install by your folks and warn them using anything outside this repo
   could/will be considered an RPE (resume producing event).
3. You can block users from using commands via PowerShell
   JEA/constrained endpoint.

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/build-constrained-powershell-endpoint-using-configuration-file
>
> https://powershell.org/2019/03/secure-your-powershell-session-with-jea-and-constrained-endpoints

You could also enable PowerShell auditing and monitor for these modules of interest, then fire off an alert to the user and remove them or ask them to, or just remove them when they are seen via the event logs, then alert the user to the removal and why.

Yet, even if you tried to block them. They could just save the module locally, give it a new name, and run it anyway.

Again, this is an HR/threat management issue that must be addressed directly to those in violation. Just as if users violated security/risk management policies. Again, an RPE in most orgs.

Comment: I will do my best to make it so. But you are right. It is a problem that we have been addressing for so long, but some still make that mistake.

Comment: I have been in orgs in my past, with the same issue. When they hired me as a Systems Analyst to resolve systems, development, ITIL issues, this admin thing and HA/DR were the first things on the agenda.  Yet, as I hit a few folks, all I got was pushback. I told the company either you want this sort of thing corrected, or you don't, and only they can make that decision. You remove the risk, manage the risk or accept the risk. Those are you options. After 3+ years of fighting with them, I ask to get reassigned to another customer as my time there was being wasted. They never passed audits.